# Why The Bar Chart On Combo Plot Of Ggplot With Two Y-Axis With Different Scale In R Not Appear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot combo plot of bar chart and line chart with two different scale y-axis by using ggplot package in r but the bar chart does not appear. Below is the input and the code:

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACa51.png)

Input data:

```
reshaped_data <-
  structure(list(
    Year = c("2014", "2014", "2016", "2016", "2019", "2019", "2022", "2022"), 
    Total_percentage = c(0.23, 0.23, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.18, 0.18), 
    Type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                     levels = c("Export", "Import"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(1020494000, 1334758000, 1243093000, 1734937000, 1551107000, 
              2155641000, 2257669000, 2433288000)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
ggplot(data = reshaped_data, aes(x = Year)) +
   geom_col(aes(y = Total_percentage, fill = "Total_percentage"), 
position = "dodge") +
   geom_line(aes(y = Value, color = Type, group = Type), size = 
1) +
   geom_point(aes(y = Value, color = Type, group = Type), size = 
3) +
   labs(
    title = "Total Percentage of Household Coffee Consumption 
against Coffee Trades in Malaysia   
From 2014 to 2022",
    x = "Year (2014-2022)",
    y = "Number of Trades (RM)"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 2500000000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::comma,
    breaks = seq(0, 2500000000, by = 500000000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = ~ (. / 1e9) * 10,  # Convert to percentage
      name = "Total Percentage of Household Coffee Consumption",
      labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 0.01)
    )
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Total Percentage of
Household Coffee Consumption") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Import" = "#B2533E", "Export" = "#B5CB99"),
    name = "Type of Trades"
  )
```

But from this code, I got:

[image: Chart that I got]

This is the output that I expected:

[image: The expected output]

Comment: Hi Nur! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're likely to get a much better response if you turn the screenshot of your code instead into text. You can use `dput(reshaped_data)` or `dput(head(reshaped_data))` to get it. Edit your question to add it in

Comment: One of your series is ~5 billion times larger than the other, so you will need to scale them to be in a more similar range. Keep in mind that secondary axes in ggplot2 are just decorations and do not scale any of the layers. perhaps something like `geom_col(aes(y = Total_percentage*1e9, ...`

Answer (score 1):

The secondary y axis is not being scaled properly. In fact, it is not being scaled at all, see the factor for the `y` aesthetic in `geom_col`.

Also, I have defined the texts to be displayed separately, with newline characters instead of hard line breaks.

```r
library(ggplot2)

fill_text <- "Total Percentage of\nHousehold Coffee\nConsumption"
title_text <- "Total Percentage of Household Coffee Consumption\nagainst Coffee Trades in Malaysia\nFrom 2014 to 2022"

ggplot(data = reshaped_data, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Total_percentage * 10e9, fill = "Total percentage"), 
           position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, color = Type, group = Type), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Value, color = Type, group = Type), size = 3) +
  labs(
    title = title_text,
    x = "Year (2014-2022)",
    y = "Number of Trades (RM)"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 2500000000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::comma,
    breaks = seq(0, 2500000000, by = 500000000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = ~ (. / 10e9),  # Convert to percentage
      name = "Total Percentage of Household Coffee Consumption",
      labels = scales::percent_format((scale = 0.01))
    )
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = fill_text, values = c(`Total percentage` = "#8064a2")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Import" = "#B2533E", "Export" = "#B5CB99"),
    name = "Type of Trades"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) It works!